# undefined contracts.contractName after compiling with solc

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, solc

After compiling a smart contract with solc. I'm hitting some issues and would love some pointers for debugging/troubleshooting.

**Description**

```
    $ node
    > var solc = require("solc")  
    > var src = `contract yoThere {
        string public msg;
        function yoThere() {
          msg = "Hey lol";
        }

        function greet() constant returns(string) {
          return msg;
        }
     }
     `

     > var comp = solc.compile(src)
```

- Check contracts

  ```
  > comp.contracts.yoThere  
  undefined
  ```

Though, if I try `comp.contracts` it returns the whole contract. What I would like to do is `comp.contracts.yoThere.bytecode` for example.

I don't know if the colon before the name `:yoThere` is an indication of something I've done wrong:

```
    > comp.contracts
    { ':yoThere': 
      { assembly: { '.code': [Array], '.data': [Object] },
      // ...
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `comp.contracts[":yoThere"].bytecode` returns what I'm looking for. I'm not sure why `:` gets added in front of the contract's name at compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to github [issue 83](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/83) for solc-js, "If you compile from something that is not a file, the compiler uses the empty file name and adds a `:` to separate filename and contract name."

This appears to have been introduced from solc 0.4.9.

Since the colon is added (as noted in the comment to the original question), `comp.contracts[":yoThere"].bytecode` provides the desired output. If having the colon added is *not* desired, compile from a file.